# (permissions: 0777) in windows IIS for php

Tags: php, iis, windows-10

I sent `CatTools` folder to `Everyone` full rights. Still I am getting permission error  for my php file.

Php Application deployed on IIS server windows 10. How to solve this?

```
Antiword binary D:\CatsTools\antiword\ is not executable (permissions: 0777).
Pdftotext binary D:\CatsTools\xpdf\bin64\ is not executable (permissions: 0777).
UnRTF binary is not executable (permissions: 0).
```

Comment: Go to IIS Manager, select your website in left pane, click double click Authentication in right pane and then right click `Anonymous Authentication` click Edit and click `Applicaiton pool identity`. After this edit CatTools folder permissions and then assign user `IIS AppPool\{Application Pool Name}` read and write permissions. App Pool identity users have naming format `II AppPool\{App Pool Name}` e.g. `IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool` is `DefaulAppPool` user

Comment: What is drive D? A mapped drive?